# What are these number cards for?

Tags: legendary-marvel

I recently bought the Civil War expansion for Marvel Legendary. In addition to the advertised contents, it also contained a number of cards with the standard Legendary back whose front was identical to the back except with the addition of a number at the lower right. There are ten with the number 1, four with the number 2, and sixteen with the number 3.

I didn't see any mention of these in the rulebook. What are they for? Do I need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those cards are just filler in the printing process, and serve no actual game purpose.

It is up to you what you do with them. Whether you throw them away, keep them in the box, or maybe even try to come up with a custom scenario that utilises them somehow.

For a bit more explanation see [this thread on boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1626829/blank-cards-numbered-1-2-or-3).

Comment: I wondered if it might be something like that. Thanks for confirming it!